# ACF Categories Missing in Live Elementor Query

Tags: wordpress, elementor, acfpro

Somehow, my ACF categories have disappeared from the Elementor posts query source, but everything works perfectly on the staging website. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

I updated my plugins, cleared the cache, and synced the library in Elementor tools.